# django authenticate() allways returns None

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to create a custom login-form for authenticating against a remote-server, so I have to create a custom login-form. I have created a user with
username='test3', password='test' in the django-shell. When I try to use the authenticate-function, I allways get None. When I try to login with same username and password, I can login. I can exclude the following possible errors:
- 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' is listed in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
```

- The password is stored as hash(I checked it with sqlite-browser)
- `User.objects.get(username='test3').check_password('test')`
  returns True
- I did syncdb, migrate and makemigrations after activating the authentication-backend

I'm using django 1.8
In principle, I only need the session-data because the users are stored in a different place.

This morning, I realized, that the problem is only solved partly:
- authenticate() works in the shell
- in my view I can retrieve the user and successfully check its password
But then again, when I try to use the authenticate()-function in my view, I get a None-type object. I even deleted the database but the behaviour is still the same.
My settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',                           
    #'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
    )
```

views:
from django.contrib.auth.models     import User
from django.contrib.auth            import authenticate

```
def authentifizieren(request):
    """
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uname = request.POST['username']
        passwd = request.POST['password']
        dbuser = User.objects.get(username=uname)
        dbuvalid=dbuser.check_password(passwd)
        auser = authenticate(username=uname, password=passwd)
        print('***************************************', dbuser,dbuvalid)
        print('***************************************', auser)
    if (auser != None):
        login(request, auser)
    return redirect('/startseite')
```

output:

```
*************************************** test True
*************************************** None
```

I also hardcoded the user/password-strings to exlude an encoding-related problem, but no success.

Comment: This problem happens only in shell or also in a view?  And you're using `authenticate(username='test3', password='test')`?  Where are you importing `authenticate()` from?

Comment: from django.contrib.auth            import authenticate

Comment: sorry clicked too fast, it happens in the view and in the shell. I just switched to the shell for faster testing.

Answer (score 0):

[`django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend) is an authentication backend and not a middleware class.

You should remove this authentication backend entry from `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` settings.

Also, you need to define `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` to something like below:

```
# Authentication backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', # default
        ..   # any other authentication backends
    )
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much, this helped. I also had to delete the testusers