# django authenticate() still allways returns None

Tags: python, django, authentication

I edited my question from yesterday:
[django authenticate() allways returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741362/django-authenticate-allways-returns-none?noredirect=1#comment53323740_32741362), but I think noone will will pay attention because I already marked the question as answered.
- authenticate() works in the shell (didn't work yesterday)
- in my view I can retrieve the user and successfully check its password
But then again, when I try to use the authenticate()-function in my view, I get a None-type object. I even deleted and recreated the database but the behaviour is still the same.
My settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',                           
    #'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
    )
```

views:
from django.contrib.auth.models     import User
from django.contrib.auth            import authenticate

```
def authentifizieren(request):
    """
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uname = request.POST['username']
        passwd = request.POST['password']
        dbuser = User.objects.get(username=uname)
        dbuvalid=dbuser.check_password(passwd)
        auser = authenticate(username=uname, password=passwd)
        print('***************************************', dbuser,dbuvalid)
        print('***************************************', auser)
    if (auser != None):
        login(request, auser)
    return redirect('/startseite')
```

output:

```
*************************************** test True
*************************************** None
```

I also hardcoded the user/password-strings to exlude an encoding-related problem, but no success.
by the way, what's a MCVE ?

Comment: Do you have an `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting?

Comment: No, but when I was searching I realized something strange:
I created a new project to test the issue in a new environment and the version in the new settings-file was 1.8.4, (I expected 1.8.2, the one I downloaded in windows), the version of the settings-file in my project I'm actuallay working on is 1.7. I did no update or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Now authenticate() works. It was a version-mismatch. Now I remember that I created the initial project at home and on my gentoo-machine there still is the version 1.7.7 installed and on the windows-machine at work 1.8.4., I think it is the different settings-file, stupid mistake from me.

Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

On django version 2.1 or above, you should pass the request into function authenticate for the customized authentication.
For example:

```
class PasswordlessAuthenticationBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, request, uid):
        try:
            token = Token.objects.get(uid=uid)
            print('got user', file=sys.stderr)
            return ListUser.objects.get(email=token.email)
        except ListUser.DoesNotExist:
            print('new user', file=sys.stderr)
            return ListUser.objects.create(email=token.email)
        except Token.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Finally, don't forget the settings in settings.py:
1. accounts is your app name
2. ListUser is your model name

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.ListUser'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'accounts.authentication.PasswordlessAuthenticationBackend',
)
```